# How do I 'mock' the behavior of child widgets in Flutter widget tests?

Tags: flutter-test

Here is my dilemma: I'm writing widget tests for some custom widget in Flutter.

```
class ParentView extends StatefulWidget {
  final NetworkCall networkCall;
  final SomeExternalResource resource;

  ParentView({this.networkCall, this.resource});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ParentViewState();
}

class _ParentViewState extends State<ParentView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnotherCustomView(),
    )
  }
}
```

It's easy to mock the behavior of network calls and other classes, but what about a child widget -- `AnotherCustomView` in this case. Let's say it also has external calls it's making, and even custom children of its own. It seems impractical to have to consider all these dependencies every time I test any widget. What can I do to solve this problem?